# Cannot open up URL with selenium python, but the browser is succesfully opened

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import datetime


ch_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
ch_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Dossy\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")


chrome = webdriver.Chrome(options=ch_options)

chrome.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

this code only open up the chromedriver with my profile, but couldn't redirect to a link

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing this:

```
ch_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
ch_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Dossy\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
```

you can directly give the path

```
ch_options = webdriver.Chrome('**HERE GIVE  YOUR FULL PATH OF chromedriver.exe**')
```

like:

```
chrome = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\Lucky\\Downloads\\.zip\\chromedriver.exe')
```

Your browser will open and it and will also redirect you to the link.

Comment: I've tried the ```chrome = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\Lucky\\Downloads\\.zip\\chromedriver.exe')``` but It doesn't use my profile, it uses the Guest account

Answer (score 1):

Try this with your correct driver path

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import datetime

chromedriver = 'path of chrome driver till chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

Answer (score 1):

Making it so simple and short:
Make sure to add the chrome driver path correctly

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import datetime

PATH = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"    # Path where u have downloaded the driver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

This will work hopefully!

Comment: I have tried the ```PATH = r"C:\PATH\to\chromedriver.exe"  ``` but It doesn't use my Chrome User Profile, instead it is using Chrome guest account

Answer (score 0):

If you have problem in first solution and try this:
First copy the of chrome driver path:
[image]

Then,go to the "This PC" and right click on it and then go to the properties:
[image]

After it go to the advanced system setting:
[image]

Then, click on Environment Variable
[image]

Then,In system variable click on Path and then click on edit:
[image]

Then, click on new :
[image]

After it,paste the copied path with \chromedriver.exe  then click on "Ok":
[image]

and click "Ok" on all the tabs
That's it
Now try it
Comment if you are having still problem in this.

Comment: Try this if having problem comment down.